# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Tags: watchos-2

I already have a Watch app written for iOS 8.2, I want to configure a Watch app for watch OS 2 and deliver both versions of mine Watch app inside the same iOS app. So I create a new Watch App Target for WatchOS2 with Xcode7.0, but it can not work.
How to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Take some time to google before you ask a question like this. You can expect to get all the answers before you try.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I have the two answers below already applied, and I'm still having this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in build settings >  under Base SDK > this is set to **latest watchOS.**

Answer (score 1):

When you make a watch target, you need to go to Build Settings for both the Watch and the Watch Extension and change Architectures/Supported Platforms from 'iOS' to 'watchOS'.

Answer (score 0):

The WatchOs2 extension should be running on the Watch Tracy, so switch it to be running on Watch in the Build Settings.